# r-OSGI ECF beginners tutorials

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-ecf, r-osgi

r-OSGI in ECF seems have less resources on the Internet. I have found several tutorials straightly explain code. But I am seeking a step by step tutorial which can explain the following.

1. How to create r-osgi Project in eclipse.
2. What are the things we need to configure in Eclipse to run that project?
3. How to Debug and run r-OSGI project in Eclipse.
4. How to write the r-OSGI Hello world Service.
5. How to write Service Discovery in ECF.

I found this Tutorial for OSGI in eclipse, will this apply for r-OSGI?
[OSGI first bundle](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html#OSGi_firstbundle)

If yes,
will all concepts which are related to OSGI apply to r-OSGI?

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?http://wiki.eclipse.org/EIG:Getting_Started_with_OSGi_Remote_Services#Adding_ECF.27_OSGi_Remote_Services_Implementation_to_Your_Target_Platform

My point of view:

Yes all the concepts for OSGI should also apply to r-OSGI. I am not super familair with r-OSGI but it looks like the primary way to enable an OSGI service to become r-OSGI is to add a property on the exported OSGI service that tells the r-OSGI runtime "take my service and apply it on a efctcp:// port". Basically: an r-OSGI services is just a standard OSGI service that has been exposed using r-OSGI. You can see that here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/ecf/org.eclipse.ecf.git/tree/examples/bundles/org.eclipse.ecf.examples.remoteservices.hello.ds.host/OSGI-INF/hello.xml

Where line 6 looks like the only one that applies to r-OSGI on the server side.

As far as debugging in eclipse, I would just disable r-osgi in my local debugging and only enable it when needed. I wonder if you can attach more than one remote debuggers in Eclipse, which you let you debug two separate systems at once, EDIT: each one running it's own OSGI runtime and talking to each other using r-OSGI.

Comment: Thanks.I already checked that eclipse wiki.But i am not sure how to work in eclipse regarding r-OSGI. If all concept is apply for  r-OSGI ,may be most of the thinks which are related to eclipse must be same.I will give another try in eclipse